# How to print Amazon S3 bucket name using Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to retrieve Amazon S3 bucket names from my AWS account but the code below doesn't seem to function the way I want it to.

```
import boto3
import json

s3client = boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3response = s3client.list_buckets()
    print(s3response)
```

If I run the code line by line in Python then I see that s3response has values in it but I can't seem to get it to print to the screen when I run the file like >>>Python listalls3buckets.py.

If I do it line by line then this is what I see;

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:55:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3, json
>>> s3client = boto3.client('s3')
>>> s3response = s3client.list_buckets(
... )
>>> s3response  
{u'Owner': {u'DisplayName': 'mylab+myLabServices-nonProd-4177', u'ID': 'c226028770a60fb45fb951e27ff6353280086514dd5c019d07a46efe892aa4f8'}, u'Buckets': [{u'CreationDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 1, 16, 47, 12, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'Name': 'sample-testbucket-delete'}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HostId': '1sFG3nzi+HTw5eHcJqC3p0PxVQhdbJ0js4z6KU45+oNaO/879uraDaOD6c2RiFKWD0HK/jH7kqA=', 'RequestId': 'E1B30DBB4114C29C', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': '1sFG3nzi+LGw5eHcJqC3p0PxVQhdbJ0js4z6KU45+oNaO/879uraDaOD6c2RiFKWD0HK/jH7kqA=', 'server': 'AmazonS3', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'x-amz-request-id': 'E1B30DBB4114C29C', 'date': 'Thu, 01 Aug 2019 18:53:41 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/xml'}}}
```

I can see that the name of bucket is "sample-testbucket-delete" but what I want is that when I run the code it simply prints out the name. Can I get some help please?

EDIT: I got to the point where I can see bucket name w/o a lot of metadata being printed out;

```
>>> s3response["Buckets"]
[{u'CreationDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 1, 16, 47, 12, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'Name': 'sample-testbucket-delete'}]
```

Now trying to get just the name printed out and then use this piece in final code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can already see, `s3response` is a dictionary containing what you need along with a bunch of other metadata; you just need to pull the contents out accordingly.

```
for bucket in s3response['Buckets']:
    print(bucket['Name'])
```